# How to configure Hudson base distribution?

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I am a total newbie to the *Hudson* administration, so my question is very 101:
I downloaded *hudson-3.0.0.war*, which is said to be just the *Hudson Core* without any plugins included, and deployed it on my *Apache Tomcat 7.0* server.
So *Hudson* as a web app is up, I can browse it, manage plugins via UI and so on.

But when I try to create my very first job as ***Build a free-style software project***, I get the following exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/hudson/utils/tasks/MetaProject

type Exception report

message java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/hudson/utils/tasks/MetaProject

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/hudson/utils/tasks/MetaProject
```

I assume that a certain plugin is missing (although I would expect that even the base distribution included such a basic task, but never mind...).
I cannot figure out which plugin I have to install in order to enable the job creation between all available plugins.

I am really hoping to any assistance with this issue, which I shall appreciate very much.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a dependency. Add to the pom.xml the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.hudson</groupId>
    <artifactId>hudson-plugin-utils</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```